# Display Component based on another component lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I have recently encountered an issue regarding the usage of one of my costum components. I have created a "Chargement" (Loading in French) Component for a project I am working on.

This component is a simple circular spinner with a dark background that when displayed, informs the user that an action is going on.

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import { CircularProgress } from 'material-ui/Progress';
import blue from 'material-ui/colors/blue';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const styles = theme => ({
  chargement: {
    position: 'fixed',
    left: '50%',
    top: '50%',
    zIndex: 1
  }
});

class Chargement extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    if (this.props.chargement) {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <div className='loadingicon'>
            <CircularProgress size={80} style={{ color: blue[500] }}/>
          </div>
          <div className='loadingBackground'/>
        </Fragment>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    chargement: state.App.chargement
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
  }, dispatch);
};

Chargement.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

let ChargementWrapped = withStyles(styles)(Chargement);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChargementWrapped);
```

This component is displayed based on a boolean variable in my redux Store called "chargement".

It works like a charm whenever I am using it to make api call and load data. However, one of the components in my Web App takes quite a bit of time to render (1-2 seconds). This component renders a pretty big list of data with expansion panels. I tried to set my display variable based on the componentWillMount and componentDidMount functions.

```
class ListView extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    this.props.setChargement(true);
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.setChargement(false);
  }
```

However with this particular case the "chargement" component never displays.

I also tried to create a "Wrapper Component" in case the issue came from my "chargement" component being somewhat related to the re-rendered component as a children. :

```
export default class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Reboot />
        <EnTete />
        <Chargement />
        <App />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The "App " component is the one that takes a few seconds to render and that I am trying to implement my "chargement" component for. I am pretty sure this as to do with the component lifecycle but everything I tried so far failed.

My current stack is : React with Redux and MaterialUi

What am I missing ?

Thanks for your help!

Ps: You might want to check the explanation and precision I added on the main answer comments as they provide further context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix my issue that does not involve the use of the "chargement" component like I had initially planned. The issue revolved around the usage of Expansion Panels from the Material-Ui-Next librairy.

The solution I found is the following :

Instead of trying to show a Loading component while my list rendered, I reduced the render time of the list by not rendering the ExpansionDetail Component unless the user clicked to expand it.

This way, the list renders well under 0.2 seconds on any devices I've tested. I set the state to collapsed: false on every panel inside the constructor.

```
class ListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      collapsed: false
    };
    this.managePanelState = this.managePanelState.bind(this);
  }
  managePanelState () {
    if (this.state.collapsed) {
      this.setState({collapsed: false});
    } else {
      this.setState({collapsed: true});
    }
  }
```

Then I use the onChange event of the expansion panel to switch the state between collapsed and not on every ListItemDetail element.

```
<ExpansionPanel onChange={() => this.managePanelState()}>
```

I guess sometimes the solution isn't where you had initially planned.
 Thanks to everyone who took time to look into my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but I think the problem is simply your API call takes more time than your component mounting cycle, which is totally normal. You can solve the problem by rearranging a bit the places where to put the IO.

Assuming you are making the API call from `AppWrapper`, dispatch the Redux action in `componentDidMount` i.e. fetchListItems(). When the API call resolves, the reducer should change its internal `loading` value from `true` to `false`. Then, `AppWrapper` will receive `chargement` as a prop and its value will be false. Therefore, you should check what this value is in `AppWrapper`'s render method. If the prop is true, you render the `Chargement` component or else, render `ListView`.

Also, try always to decouple the IO from the view. It's quite likely that you'll need to reuse Chargement in other situations, right? Then, make it a simple, generic component by just rendering the view. Otherwise, if you need to reuse the component, it will be coupled to one endpoint already. For this, you can use a *Stateless Functional Component* as follows:

```
const Chargement = () =>
    <Fragment>
        <div className='loadingicon'>
            <CircularProgress size={80} style={{ color: blue[500] }}/>
        </div>
        <div className='loadingBackground'/>
    </Fragment>
```

Comment: You are definately right about my api call taking more time than my component mounting cycle. However I wanted to bring a precision that might clarify a bit my issue. I am using 2 components that dictate how to display the data. I am trying to implement my "Chargement" component whenever I am switching from one way of displaying the data to another i.e.:  When my "App" component renders a different view Component . Feel free to correct me if I did not understand your answer corectly and thanks for your help!

Comment: Alright, assuming you have a component A and B for displaying the data (i.e. a list and a table), when you click on a button to toggle the view, you need to run a callback that will dispatch the Redux action to fetch the data you need (if you don't have that data already) and also to set the internal state of AppWrapper with the view it needs to render, like this:

```
handleSwitchView = (viewMode) => {
    if (!this.props.data) {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.fetchData
    }

    this.setState({
         viewMode,
    })
}
```

Comment: Then in AppWrapper's render, you need to check first if you are loading. If so, you render the spinner. Else, you check the value of `viewMode` from the state, and render the corresponding viewComponent. Does this help? Maybe I misunderstood the problem

Comment: You are close ! Sorry if im not so clear with my explanation, I basically already implement my Loading component like you described. My issue is that when I render the corresponding viewComponent, (since there is a lot of data) several seconds can go by where the user cannot interact with the system. However there are no clear signs of this, hence why I am trying to render the loading component the moment my application starts rendering the viewComponent. Then, once the viewComponent is done rendering I dispatch my store to change the value of the "chargement" variable to false.

Comment: But this implementation does not show my "chargement" component at all. Which is what I am trying to investigate.